# How was BODMAS rule defined?

Tags: arithmetic

This is a bit naive question bu help me out here.
We know that in Arithmetic,  we follow the BODMAS rule where first preference is given to Brackets then Exponent then Division and so on.

My question is how did we arrive at the conclusion to give the following preference. Was it conventional or has some theoretical twist in it?

Comment: Probably because multiplication is more powerful than addition (we do not need to write down a number extremely often) and exponention more powerful than multiplication (the same with the factors). Finally, the brackets are for breaking the rules, if the expression should be interpreted in another way.